# Return null or zero when in operator does not return records

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm trying to aggregate the total value of a large number products from a very large data set under certain conditions and was wondering if there was a way to return null or 0 if any of the values in my in operator do not return a record. So let's say my query is set up as follows (I apologize as I cannot post actual table and column names):

```
Select A.1, A.2, B.1, sum(D.1 * E.1) total 

from A, B, C, D, E

where ... [a bunch of joins to connect the tables]

and A.2 in ('aaaa', 'aaab', 'aaac', etc... many values are here) 

and ... [more parameters]
```

At the moment it returns all the data I need, however, I'd also like it to return rows with null or 0's in the columns where the in operator does not find a match. Also, one of my limitations is that I CANNOT create any tables.

Thanks

Comment: It's not too clear what you're asking for. Maybe you could provide some example data and expected output?

Comment: There's a missing `GROUP BY` somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

Doing this requires a left outer join.  Here is an approach to fit into your query:

```
with list as (
      select 'aaaa' as name from dual union all
      select 'aaab' from dual union all
      . . .
     )
Select A.1, l.name, B.1, sum(D.1 * E.1) total 
from list l left outer join
     A
     on l.name = A.2 . . . , B, C, D, E
where ... [a bunch of joins to connect the tables] and
      ... [more parameters];
```

I would suggest that you change your syntax to use standard `join` syntax, rather than implicit joins in the `where`.

You can do this directly with your query as well:

```
with list as (
      select 'aaaa' as name from dual union all
      select 'aaab' from dual union all
      . . .
     ),
     yourresults as (
      your query goes here
     )
select yr.1, l.2, yr.3, total
from list l left outer join
     yourresults yr
     on l.name = yr.2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is Oracle then you can use the partitioned outer join syntax to perform this operation (known as data densification).

The best technique would be to join between the A, B, C, D, E tables in a common table expression and partition outer join to another common table expression in which you generate one row for each of the IN clause values.

Lookup partition outer join in the docs for guidance and examples, and there are other questions on SO about normalising comma separated lists.